# Calculating daily volumes from total volume

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I have the following data:

| ID | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-09-03 | 0 |
| A | 2021-09-04 | 12 |
| A | 2021-09-05 | 37 |
| A | 2021-09-06 | 40 |
| B | 2021-08-03 | 20 |
| B | 2021-08-04 | 43 |
| B | 2021-08-05 | 75 |

And from this data, I would like to get the following table:

| ID | Date | Total | Daily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-09-03 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2021-09-04 | 12 | 12 |
| A | 2021-09-05 | 37 | 25 |
| A | 2021-09-06 | 40 | 3 |
| B | 2021-08-03 | 20 | 20 |
| B | 2021-08-04 | 43 | 23 |
| B | 2021-08-05 | 75 | 32 |

I tried the following code, but I get a lot of duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE table_b AS (
SELECT a.ID, a.Date, a.Total,
a.Total - coalesce(b.Total, 0) AS Daily
FROM table_a a left outer JOIN table_a b
ON (a.ID = b.ID AND b.Date < a.Date));
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: and is table_b a secret ?

Comment: No? It is the table that is created with the attached code, but I would like it to be like I have shown in the description.

Comment: you join a table_b and try to create a table_b that doesn't work in mysql, so the inner table_b  must exist prior of running the code, please correct the query, as so it doesn't make sense what you try to subtract

Comment: Ahh my bad, it was a typo. Now it is fixed.

Comment: table is a restricted word and can't be used in a query, so you try to generated a running sum?

Comment: which version of mysql do you use?

Comment: I am using 8.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,
       Total - COALESCE(LAG(Total) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `date`), 0) Daily
FROM src_table
```